# ASP.NET Crystal Report change "Set Datasource Location" is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to setup a test platform for a Live application upgrade. In order not to mess up my Live data, I duplicated the database to another database. And update my CR using "Set Datasource Location" and point to the new DB. However, they are still loading records from the live DB! FYI I am connecting using ODBC and I have created a test ODBC for the test platform.

[image]
Previously my DC is "osso_odbc", but I have updated it to "ossotest", but it is still loading record from "osso_odbc".

Anybody know what went wrong and what I should do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1 - If "save data in the report" is checked, old data can still be prompt
2 - If you have subreports you must "set datasource location" for subreports, too
3 - "Set datasource Location" is not sointuitive, did you use righr procedure
4 - We are talking about changing datasource in design time, not in asp.net runitme, are we?

---

I use the following code to programmatically change connection, based on a connectionsting and to pass parameters to the report, based on Querystring.

```
 bool Logon(ReportDocument cr, string server, string db, bool integratedSecurity, string id, string pass)
{
    ConnectionInfo ci = new ConnectionInfo();
    SubreportObject subObj;

    ci.ServerName = server;
    ci.DatabaseName = db;
    if (integratedSecurity)
        ci.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    else
    {
        ci.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        ci.UserID = id;
        ci.Password = pass;
    }
    PassParameters();
    if (!ApplyLogon(cr, ci))
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < cr.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects.Count; i++)
        if (cr.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[i].Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
        {
            subObj = (SubreportObject)cr.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[i];
            if (!ApplyLogon(cr.OpenSubreport(subObj.SubreportName), ci))
                return false;
        }
    return true;
}


 bool ApplyLogon(ReportDocument cr, ConnectionInfo ci)
{

    TableLogOnInfo li;
    // for each table apply connection info
    for (int i = 0; i < cr.Database.Tables.Count; i++)
    {

        li = cr.Database.Tables[i].LogOnInfo;
        li.ConnectionInfo = ci;
        cr.Database.Tables[i].ApplyLogOnInfo(li);

        // check if logon was successful
        // if TestConnectivity returns false, check
        // logon credentials
        if (TestConnectivity(cr, i))
        {
            // drop fully qualified table location
            if (cr.Database.Tables[i].Location.IndexOf(".") > 0)
                cr.Database.Tables[i].Location = cr.Database.Tables[i].Location.Substring(cr.Database.Tables[i].Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

     cr.Database.Tables[i].Location.Substring(cr.Database.Tables[i].Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        }

        else return false;
    }
    return true;
   }




 private static bool TestConnectivity(ReportDocument cr, int i)
{
    bool test = false;
    try { test = cr.Database.Tables[i].TestConnectivity(); }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
    {
        try { test = cr.Database.Tables[i].TestConnectivity(); }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            try { test = cr.Database.Tables[i].TestConnectivity(); }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
            { test = cr.Database.Tables[i].TestConnectivity(); }
        }
    }

    return test;
   }


  private void PassParameters()
{
    // char[] subReportPrefix = new char[] { 'P', 'm', '-', '?' };
    foreach (ParameterField field in reportDocument.ParameterFields)
    {
        string fieldName = field.Name.TrimStart('@');//.TrimStart(subReportPrefix);
        ParameterValues p = new ParameterValues();
        string valu = clearQueryString[fieldName];//cerco in querystring
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valu))//se ho trovato in querystring ok
        {
            string[] valus = valu.Split('§');//se c'è il separatore sono values sennò è value
            if (valus.Length > 1)
            {
                foreach (string v in valus)
                    if (p.Count == 0 || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v))
                        p.AddValue(v);
            }
            else
                p.AddValue(valu);
            field.CurrentValues = p;
        }
     ......
```

Comment: 1 - May I know what function is this?
2 - No subreport.
3 - I selected "Set datasource location", click on the new Datasource and click "Update". Then I "Verify Database".
4 - Yes it is design time, I compile the whole thing and execute, still loading old record. 

Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: "save data in the report" is a checkbox that is prompt when you click on report preview - look here http://scn.sap.com/thread/3275408

Comment: I am testing by running the application, not from the previews, is it related? By the way I have uploaded a screenshot above. Any clue? Tq.

Comment: if "save data.." is checked, it will not work even running the application. Before other actions, you have to verify it is unchecked.

Comment: Hi, it is unchecked, but still not loading properly. May I know if you have any idea how to set the connection string dynamically in my .cs file prior to opening the report? Example load from the connString from my web.config? Crystal report is always full of trouble.

Comment: Could it be due to Team Foundation Server is locking some of the files which is not automatically uncheck when edit the data source, thus still holding the original value?

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I did is remove all the existing connection and re-create all the form elements. Now it is working.